# Package theme for prestashop 1.6?

Tags: package, themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a reference design. Now I want to make a theme package for 1.6. So that someone will take the package and will simply upload the package and the site will come same as the design. 
I have searched over google for free package theme for prestashop 1.6 but did not got any free theme for 1.6 .
So can someone kindly tell me how to do a package theme for 1.6? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `ZIP` archive with this structure :

```
themes/your_theme_name/[the files and folders inside your theme]
```

If you don't want to create a theme from scratch, copy the default theme (`responsive` + `bootstrap`) of `prestashop 1.6` and edit it.

In fact, to install a new theme, you don't have to create an archive, you just have copy the default theme folder and edit it.

Here is the [designer documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Designer+Guide) for `prestashop 1.5`, I don't think anything has changed since (just the default skin that has been highly improved) because the core hasn't changed.